# C++ library/file format for exporting 3D skeletal animations?

Tags: c++, animation, 3d, file-format

I'm writing an application for creating 3D skeletal animations. I'm currently using Blender for modeling/rigging, export, then load and render the model with OGRE. But I'm stuck when it comes to exporting.

I'd like to be able to export the finished animated model/scene to some known file format, so that it can be imported back into Blender for rendering. So what's the best way to get the animated skeleton/armature back into Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think COLLADA is the way to go when it comes to file formats. I'm unsure about the library. FCOLLADA is dead, I'm not sure how up-to-date it is. The latest version of [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/index.html) had COLLADA export functionality added to it, but unfortunately not for animation yet. There's [OpenCOLLADA](http://opencollada.org/), which doesn't seem to be well documented, but there's two plug-ins which are probably better examples than any tutorial. Lastly there's [COLLADA DOM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/collada-dom/).

Comment: I also think Collada is the best choice here. If you want to store mesh,skeleton and animation in one file I don't know any other format that is as widely supported as Collada.

Comment: I've implemented a reader/writer using collada dom. Since Collada is very flexible the implementation is not that easy. But I think its worth the effort. If you just want to store the skeleton also take a look at Biovision BVH format. Easy to implement and also supported by some tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about FBX? It is widely used as an exchange format for geometry and animation. It support bones/joints which should fit for your skeletal animation.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX
Autodesk Page: http://usa.autodesk.com/fbx/

Comment: FBX seems nice, but I'm not sure if it can be imported into Blender. Apparently the FBX script only supports export. Thank you though.